# Sum of difference equation involving hypergeometric functions 1F0

Tags: hypergeometric-functions, difference-equations

I'm trying to prove the sum of a sequence given by

$a_{n+1} = \frac{nb-x}{(n+1)b} a_n$

with $a_1 = 1$. This gives the solution $a_n = \frac{(-x/b)_n}{n!}$. When trying to work out what this sums to, I looked at hypergeometric functions ${}_1F_0(-x/b;;1)$ to sum this, but this appears to be undefined.
I have another results saying that $a_1 = x/b$, and Mathematica seems to agree,

Sum[Pochhammer[1/3, n - 1]/Gamma[1 + n], {n, 1, Infinity}] = 3/2
but I can't see why.

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you give for $a_{n+1} = \frac{nb-x}{(n+1)b} a_n$ has a missing factor, I think it should read
$$a_n=-\frac{b}{x}\frac{(-x/b)_n}{n!}.$$ 
Then the sum over $n$ equals 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =\frac{b}{x},$$
as follows from the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (p)_n\frac{z^n}{n!}=(1-z)^{-p}$$
(here is a [derivation](http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/~gvm/radovi/AP-JIS2.pdf) --- page 2)